# Limit SQLite 3 FTS to exact phrase match

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

I have an SQLite FTS query:

```
select * from fts where text match "xml encoding" limit 10
```

It returns results like this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <html
```

But I want to just find items containing exactly **xml encoding**, but SQLite engine applies a default **NEAR** value to query.

How can I remove this near, order sort results so first display exact phrases, then phrases matching near values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `"`:

```
select * from fts where text match '"xml encoding"' limit 10
```